# how to generate .EDMX using EF6

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application inside VS2012. now i have upgrade my EF from version 5  to version 6, using Nuget tool.
but on this link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx) it is mentioned that i need to use "EF 6x code generation template" to have my .edmx file using EF6 . so i installed the EF6 tools for VS2012. and now i want to map my database to my EF. usually on asp.net mvc4 + EF-5 i do the follow:-

1. right click on Model folder.
2. select data.
3. select "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".
   as follow:-
   [image]

but now as i am using EF6 , can i still select "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" or i need to select EF 6.x DbContextGenerator ? can anyone adivce on this please? now if i am not wrong select "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" inside VS2012 will automatically use "EF 5.X DbContext Generator" ? is this correct?

Comment: See the link, the third bullet.

Comment: @GertArnold which link ?